# Django: How to display a pdf file in a new tab?

Tags: python, django

Most of the posts showing how to open a pdf file in a new tab are 3 years old. What is the best way in Django to open a pdf file uploaded to a model?

**invoice.py**

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='estimates/', blank =True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank =True)    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**views.py**

```
def view_invoice(request, invoice_id):
    invoice = get_object_or_404(Invoice, pk=invoice_id)
    return render(request, 'index_invoice.html', {'invoice': invoice})
```

**index_invoice.html**

```
<a href=""><i class="fas fa-eye"></i>&nbsp;</a>
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the `FileField`'s url:

```
<a href="{{ invoice.file.url }}"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i>&nbsp;</a>
```

Comment: Feel free to mark the answer as accepted if it works for you! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
<a href="{{ invoice.file.url }}" target="_blank"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i>&nbsp;</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Into the link add:

```
<a href="{{ invoice.pdf.url }}" target="_blank"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i>&nbsp;</a>
```